# How do I generate a URL outside of a controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, html-helper

How do I generate a URL pointing to a controller action from a helper method outside of the controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Accessing Url.GenerateUrl from Outside the Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722352/asp-net-mvc-accessing-url-generateurl-from-outside-the-controller)

Comment: I assume you are not talking about the View's UrlHelper either?

Comment: None of the answers are truly *an answer* at all.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Pass UrlHelper to your helper function and then you could do the following:

```
public SomeReturnType MyHelper(UrlHelper url, // your other parameters)
{
   // Your other code

   var myUrl =  url.Action("action", "controller");

  // code that consumes your url
}
```

Comment: umm, if you already have the UrlHelper, why call this method?

Comment: @hunter: OP has a helper, he needs the url in that helper, I am suggesting that passin UrlHelper to his helper to generate the url he wants. I edited my answer to make it more clear on what I am trying to suggest.

Comment: Cant I access UrlHelper from a static class or something built in asp.net mvc? Without passing the  UrlHelper.

Comment: Not useful to implement, e.g., a read-only Url property in a model class.

Answer (score 101):

You could use the following if you have access to the `HttpContext`:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
```

Comment: This should really be the correct answer.  Just pass the object into the method (current correct answer) is a bit too obvious and is not UrlHelper specific.

Comment: Was able to provide via injection (Autofac) with the following line;
`builder.Register(context => new UrlHelper(context.Resolve<RequestContext>())).InstancePerRequest();`

Comment: worth to say using the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace and not the `System.Web.Http.Routing`, because this class is exists in those two namespace

Answer (score 6):

You can use LinkGenerator . It's new feature in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing namespace and has been added in Aug 2020 .

At first you have to inject that in your class :

```
public class Sampleervice 
{
        private readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;

        public Sampleervice (LinkGenerator linkGenerator)
       {
            _linkGenerator = linkGenerator;
       }

       public string GenerateLink()
       { 
             return _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction("Privacy", "Home");
       }
}
```

For more information check [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/ControllerLinkGeneratorExtensions.cs#L84)

Answer (score 2):

Using L01NL's answer, it might be important to note that Action method will also get current parameter if one is provided. E.g:

editing project with id = 100
Url is `http://hostname/Project/Edit/100`

`urlHelper.Action("Edit", "Project")`
returns `http://hostname/Project/Edit/100`

while `urlHelper.Action("Edit", "Project", new { id = (int?) null });` 
returns `http://hostname/Project/Edit`

Answer (score 1):

Since you probably want to use the method in a View, you should use the `Url` property of the view. It is of type `UrlHelper`, which allows you to do

```
<%: Url.Action("TheAction", "TheController") %>
```

If you want to avoid that kind of string references in your views, you could write extension methods on `UrlHelper` that creates it for you:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string UrlToTheControllerAction(this UrlHelper helper)
    {
        return helper.Action("TheAction", "TheController");
    }
}
```

which would be used like so:

```
<%: Url.UrlToTheControllerTheAction() %>
```