# How do I generate a URL outside of a controller in ASP.NET WebApi 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

How do I generate a URL pointing to a controller action from a helper method outside of the controller in ASP.net WebApi 2?

```
return new UrlHelper().Link("DefaultApi", new
{
    Controller = "MyController",
    Action = "MyAction"
});
```

**UPDATE 1**

Generating URL in WebApi is different from ASP.net MVC

**UPDATE 2**

Here is route config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultApi",
    "API/{Controller}/{Action}"
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate a URL outside of a controller in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907540/how-do-i-generate-a-url-outside-of-a-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: No, Generating URL in WebApi is different from ASP.net MVC

Comment: Yes its quite different but strategy is the same. Just pass the `HttpRequestMessage` to the helper class and generate link. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I overcame this:

### RouteConfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

### Helper Class

```
public static string GenerateLink(HttpRequestMessage httpRequest)
{
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(httpRequest).Route("DefaultApi", new
    {
        Controller = "MyController",
        Action = "MyAction"
    });

    return httpRequest.RequestUri.Scheme + "://" + httpRequest.RequestUri.Authority + urlHelper;
}
```

And finally the `api controller` which calls the helper class:

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Default()
    {
        var link = HelperClass.GenerateLink(Request);
        return link;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this example UrlHelper return null

Comment: @Mehran It is critical to pass `Request` into `GenerateLink()` method like `HelperClass.GenerateLink(Request)`. Otherwise `HttpRequestMessage httpRequest` will be null inside `GenerateLink()` method

Comment: Yes, I pass Request into GenerateLink method like HelperClass.GenerateLink(Request) but HttpRequestMessage httpRequest is null

Comment: @Mehran Well, this is another problem and you must post a new question and show your code structure and ask why `Request` is `null` inside controller. Or at least please update your current question and address the new problem.

Comment: I apologize for the wrong answer, Request is not null in controller! in fact new UrlHelper(httpRequest).Route(...) return null

Comment: `.Route(...)` must be initialized according to your `RouteConfig` file. Please update your question and show us your route config. Maybe your route name is different than `"DefaultApi"` or your template is different than `"api/{controller}/{action}"`

Comment: My mistake again